# Lumen database seeding error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen, laravel-seeding

I'm learning back-end development with Laravel's Lumen framework, and I am writing database seeding class following [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding). Below are the codes:

Model `app\Photo.php`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Photo extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'link', 'category_id', 'date'
    ];
}
```

Model factory `database\factories\ModelFactory.php`

```
$factory->define(App\Photo::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'link' => 'https://placehold.it/' . mt_rand(200, 400),
        'category_id' => rand(1, 6),
        'date' => date("Y-m-d", mt_rand(1263618000, 1481428800))
    ];
});
```

`DatabaseSeeder` and `PhotoTableSeeder` classes `database\seeds\DatabaseSeeder.php`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
         $this->call('PhotoTableSeeder');
    }
}

class PhotoTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Photo::class, 10)->create();
    }
}
```

Previously the table name in MySQL database was `photos` and the seeding works perfectly using the command `php artisan db:seed`:

> Seeded: PhotoTableSeeder

But when I changed the table name to `photo` and run the same command, these errors occured:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.photos' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `photos` (`link`, `category_id`, `date`) values (https://placehold.it/259, 3, 2012-05-28))
>
> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.photos' doesn't exist

I don't know why the old table name is still called. I guess it was saved somewhere or am I missing something, I can't figure out the cause of the error.

Comment: so.. so far lookin on your code nothing named [`migrations`](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#migrations) seen.. well, to elaborate a bit more, migrations used to create the table, models used to represent one row in the table, while factory to create seeds, while seeders, insert seed into database..

Comment: also laravel always assume table name is the plural name of the model.. - ie. photo as photos.. can be overriden with `protected $table` sorry for sidetracking..

Comment: Use `DB::table('photo')` to select the specified table.

Comment: @solarhell as Bagus and Eric said, table name override in model is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent looks for the Plural form of the Model Class Name as the table in the database. So in this case it was expecting to find a table called "Photos"

if for some reason you need to name the table Photo you can always override the default by adding

```
protected $table = 'photo';
```

to your photo model class. I tend to do this even when I am using the default conventions just as a note to myself exactly which table a model is referencing